# Java GUI Jframe Exception handling

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, exception, try-catch

I have a GUI design that has a number of fields that the user enters. I'm using a `try-catch` to deal with the exceptions that the user incorrectly enters. I was successful when the user enters a String into a number field (My `id` field) but I'm frustrated here trying to use an exception to handle when a user enters an integer into a text/String field. 
Here is my code to give you an idea of what I did for the exception i did successfully. Thank you.

```
try {

    String taskID = txtId.getText();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(taskID);

    String taskName = txtName.getText();

    String taskDesc = txtDesc.getText();

    boolean isCompleted = chkComp.isSelected();

    int taskPriority = comboPriority.getSelectedIndex();

    Task newTask = new Task(id, taskName, taskDesc, isCompleted, taskPriority);

    tasks.add(newTask);
    taskMod.addElement(newTask);

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: You must enter an integer");

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, But what time op exception will that be? Like this was a "NumberFormatException"? Sorry i'm new to learning this.

Comment: Well I'm a little confused here. Is your goal to get the program to prompt again?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to prompt the user "You must enter A String in Name not an integer"..sorry if i'm not making much sense. My Goal is to get it to prompt for either error

Answer (score 1):

I have another option for you, You can validate the input in real time, with a `DocumentFilter`. With this, you validate each character input. If the character does not match what you want, it won't be allowed to be entered.

Here is for numbers only

```
private JTextField createNumberField() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }
    });
    return field; 
}
```

Here is for name (letters, - , and spaces) are allowed

```
private JTextField createNameField() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s\\-]", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s\\-]", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
        }
    });
    return field;
}
```